# Can I implement Active Directory when my application is hosted another place.

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am using `C#` and `Asp.net` for developing the application and host same into some hosting service provider.

I need to authenticate users from `Active Directory` from different location.
Say for example my application is hosted on `Asphost.com` and the url of app is `test.abc.co.in`.The said sub domain is for `Test` client.

So how to use `Test` client `Active directory` users from my app.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, this is not a C# or Asp.net problem, but a networking issue.
The Active directory is within the client's internal network and protected by firewalls that are not reachable from the location where you deploy the application.

Comment: So how can i achieve above scenario ?

Comment: The client should open up his firewall to allow LDAP or better LDAPs connections from the external network. Another option would be to do it over a VPN connection or something like that. All of these proposals are however quite a security issue and I assume that the client won't accept it